# opencv4android sdk compiler flags/ ndk version

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to compile opencv4android from trunk (by following http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Trunk_OpenCV_for_Android). My project runs fine with the precompiled OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk but fails with the one I am building with Android NDK r9c for target ABI x86. I have tried compiling with both x86-4.6 and 4.8 toolchains (with c++0x and c++11 respectively) but I am still getting errors. Does anyone know what ndk version was used when the prebuilt opencv4android sdk was built?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which NDK version was used for building the prebuits, but right now OpenCV supports NDK r5->r9c, x86 and x86_64

Using the NDK r9d 64-bit on linux, I ran:

`git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git
export ANDROID_NDK=/opt/android-ndk
cd opencv/platforms
sh ./scripts/cmake_android_x86.sh
cd build_android_x86
make -j16
adb install bin/opencv_test_java.apk
adb shell am instrument -w org.opencv.test/.OpenCVTestRunner`

and all the 1733 tests went ok.

Maybe there is something else wrong with your project, what errors are you getting ?